# Password should not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters

Tags: c#, regex

Actually, I have a little problem is I am working on app having in which a form to register user and on validation end password must not contain user's name, and must not contains consecutive 2 letters form user's name.

Suppose user name id "Aspnetmvc"
then password should not contain whole word  "Aspnetmvc" or even part of user name as asp, net, mvc.
This can be solve by customize logic but what I wants to do is to be solved by programming logic, but what I want to do is to find out way solve this problem with regular expression.

Any one have idea about this C#?

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do this in a regex?

Comment: How is "customize logic" and "programming logic" different? Also, not ever problem needs to be solved with Regex's =D

Comment: I am being snarky but this reminds me of: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/22/558007.aspx

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution is to create a method which will extract all possible 3 letter combinations from the username and the realname and check whether these are part of the password. The method for each possible part of 3 characters (exceeds 2) can be written as a simple extension method and then you can just use the `IEnumerable.Any` method to see if any of these parts are part of the password:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "1234567890";

            string username = "125689";
            string realName = "890";

            bool usernameOk = !username.AllPartsOfLength(3)
                .Any(part => password.Contains(part));
            bool realNameOk = !realName.AllPartsOfLength(3)
                .Any(part => password.Contains(part));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> AllPartsOfLength(this string value, int length)
        {
            for (int startPos = 0; startPos <= value.Length - length; startPos++)
            {
                yield return value.Substring(startPos, length);
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

I find this a lot easier to read than any solution containing a regular expression.

You could even do:

```
passwordOk = !username.AllPartsofLength(3)
    .Concat(realName.AllPartsOfLength(3))
    .Any(part => password.Contains(part));
```

As these use lazy evaluation, evaluation will stop when the first part is found.

There really is no need, or good reason to try and do this with a regular expression. The only expression you could use is an expression that checks for the existence of any 3-letter-part in the string. so you'll still have to split the string into parts of 3, then build an expression, let the runtime build a statemachine for that, check it against the input and then discard the expression. It's way to expensive for the problem at hand.

It would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> parts = username.AllPartsOfLength(3)
    .Concat(realName.AllPartsOfLength(3))
    .Select(part => Regex.Escape(part));

string regex = "(" + string.Join("|", parts) + ")";

bool isPasswordOk = !Regex.Match(regex).Success;
```

---

**Benchmark added**

As requested by sln, a short benchmark:

> Method: StringManipulationOnly
>   Time taken: 26,0015ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.
>
> Method: RegexStringJoinAllParts
>   Time taken: 486,0278ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.
>
> Method: RegexZeroWidthPlusOneAndDotSplat
>   Time taken: 5686,3252ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.
>
> Method: RegexZeroWidth
>   Time taken: 2659,1521ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.

**Edit**
Did another test with th e.* removed, but the extra . kept in there

> Method: RegexZeroWidthPlusOne
>   Time taken: 2601,1488ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.

As you can see the either the `.*` is causing another 50% delay and all solutions using regex to split the strings are much slower than using string.Join to create one big expression. The clear winner, by far, is not using Regex.

The explanation for the fact that `.*constant` is slower than `constant` is likely due to the fact that .* will first grab the whole input and will then start to backtrack (from the end of the string) to find the constant, while `constant` will just look for the first occurrence of `constant`.

A simple test seems to confirm this (using `.*?` instead of `.*`):

> Method: RegexZeroWidthPlusOneDotSplatReluctant
>   Time taken: 2646,1514ms. Passed: 3333. Failed 6666.

I did do a few changes to the code, I removed case sensitivity checking (not requested by the OP) I removed argument validation, I changed the code to fail early. That ensures a fair comparison between the different methods. [The code can be found here](http://pastebin.com/jTeXS4f7).

Comment: There could be an overlap if you compare something vs catted username with realname.

Comment: @sln The username and the realname aren't catted, the list of possible parts are. it's not like (username + realname).AllPartsOfLength

Comment: But it's ListOfAllUsernameParts + ListOfAllRealNameParts

Comment: i wanted to apply same logic using jQuery and your answer saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

You should let a regex do the work for you `(?=(..)).`

**redo 4-29**

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Password = "(O*@aJY^+{PC";
        string Account  = "email@Abc.com";
        string Name     = "Ted Nelson";
        if (Password.IsNotSequentialChars(Account, 2) && Password.IsNotSequentialChars(Name, 2))
            Console.WriteLine("Passed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
    }

    public static bool IsNotSequentialChars(this string Src, string Dest, int check_len)
    {
        if (check_len < 1 || Src.Length < check_len) return true;
        Match m = Regex.Match(Src, "(?=(.{" + check_len + "})).");
        bool bOK = m.Success;

        while (bOK && m.Success)
        {
            // Edit: remove unnecessary '.*' from regex.
            // And btw, is regex needed at all in this case?
            bOK = !Regex.Match(Dest, "(?i)" + Regex.Escape(m.Groups[1].Value)).Success;
            if (!bOK)
                Console.WriteLine("Destination contains " + check_len + " sequential source letter(s) '" + m.Groups[1].Value + "'");
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        return bOK;
    }
}
```

Benchmarks are welcome...

Comment: But why not use a simple string.Substring instead. Much faster and easier to read.

Comment: As the Regex engine will automatically advance to the next character on any zero width length expression, you could simply use `(?=(..))` instead of `((?=..).)`. Also, as `.Metach()` will not surround the expression with `^..$`, there's no need to add a .* to the second expression. All in all, there's still no need to use regex here, as all operations are basic string manipulations (substring/contains)

Comment: @jessehouwing - Adressing your concerns; (1) If you don't consume, it will retry the current position before advancing the current position. Under the debugger it says `Match possible, but length=0 is smaller than requested=1, failing!`. In essence, it matches the current position twice before moveing on, exactly doubling the compute time. (2) There is absolutely no difference between `.*constant` and `constant`, none whatsoever. The engine finds `constant' immediatly in both cases. You can certainly benchmark substr vs regex in this case. Let me know!

Comment: From the docs: Usually, NextMatch begins the search for the next match exactly where the previous match left off. However, after an empty match, the NextMatch method advances by one character before trying the next match. This behavior guarantees that the regular expression engine will progress through the string. Otherwise, because an empty match does not result in any forward movement, the next match would start in exactly the same place as the previous match, and it would match the same empty string repeatedly.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch.aspx

Comment: As for constant vs .*constant, there is no speed difference in matching, but the creation of the Match object and groups will be slightly slower. On top of that I consider it just bad form. .* is redundant here and only causes clutter.

Comment: Added benchmark to my answer.

Comment: Coming back to the `.*`, of course there is a speed difference, doh, the `.*` will first grab the whole possible input, after which the engine will start backtracking. You'll probably see that .*? is faster if the input is longer and tat the omission of .* is the fastest as you leave the optimization to the engine.

Comment: @jessehouwing - Yes, of course `constant` is about twice (or more) as fast as `.*constant`. I said there was no difference with respect to the final result. In my case it was an artifact from a previous incarnation, given the brevity that that the OP's case is not thought out or real-world, I didn't care to change it after you pointed it out. Other than this, that thing with position advances automatically on an `empty match`, does not live in a vacuum. In my benchmarks using a Perl regex engine, that decision process consumes %10-%20 overhead as opposed to proactively consuming a character.

Comment: And btw, thanks for the benchmark efforts!